# NullReferenceException when Starting Workflow from TimerJob

Tags: 2007, workflow, timer-jobs

I am creating a TimerJob that invokes the workflow. Refer to the `Execute` method

```
    public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
    {
            var reader = new ConfigReader(this.configPath);
            var config = reader.GetConfiguration();

            using (var siteCollection = new SPSite(config.SiteURL))
            using (var site = siteCollection.RootWeb)
            {
                var taskList = site.Lists[config.ListName];
                var manager = taskList.ParentWeb.Site.WorkflowManager;
                var wfAssociation = taskList.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName(
                        config.WorkflowName,
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

                foreach (SPListItem item in taskList.Items)
                {
                    manager.StartWorkflow(item, wfAssociation, wfAssociation.AssociationData, true);
                }
            }
    }
```

After running the code, a `NullReferenceException` was thrown. Refer to the stack trace below

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.PrepForWorkflowTemplate(SPWorkflowTemplate
wt)
   at
Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.StartWorkflowElev(SPList
Item item, SPFile file, SPWorkflowAssociation association, SPWorkflowEvent startEvent, Boolean bAutoStart, Boolean bCreateOnly)
   at
Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Star
tWorkflow>b__0()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevatedWrapper(Object
state)
   at
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivi
leges>b__2()
   at
Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunEle
vated secureCode)
   at
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
secureCode, Object param)
   at
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunEleva
ted secureCode)
   at
Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(SPListItem
item, SPWorkflowAssociation association, SPWorkflowEvent startEvent, Boolean bAutoStart, Boolean bCreateOnly)
   at
Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(SPListItem
item, SPWorkflowAssociation association, String eventData, Boolean
isAutoStart)
   at
Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.StartWorkflow(SPListItem
item, SPWorkflowAssociation association, String eventData)
   at Exelon.CorpAppEvents.WorkflowInvokerTimerJob.Execute(Guid
targetInstanceId)
```

I checked the `tasklist`, `manager`, and `wfAssociation` and none of them are `null`. Moreover, I granted `NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users` to check if I have a permission issue, but I still get the same error.

Now, where should I look to resolve the issue. Thanks.